# PHP Notice: undefined variable, but they are already defined

Tags: php, variables, undefined

In my PHP script I get the error `variable $command_in_hostfile undefined`.

There are two functions in my class.

In the first function I return an array (`$command_in_hostfile`) to use it in another function.

However, I get the error "variable undefined" and I don´t understand why. Can anyone help me rectify this error?

Code:

```
include_once('service_function.php');

if(isset($_POST['edit_cfg_file']))
{
    $Host = new Host;
    $Host->write_hostfile();        
}

public $command_in_hostfile = array();

class Host
{
    public $command_in_hostfile = array();

    function read_services()
    {   
        ...
        $command_in_hostfile[0] = array_merge($command_in_hostfile[0]);
        $command_in_hostfile[1] = array_merge($command_in_hostfile[1]);
        return($command_in_hostfile);
    }

    function write_hostfile()
    {
        foreach($command_in_hostfile[0] as $key=>$value)
        {
        $checkcommand[$key] = "check_command ".$value."!".$value2_converted."\n";
        }   
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `$this->command_in_hostfile[0]`. You need to learn proper OOP syntax.

Comment: Also, what are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: I try to read the values of the array in the function read_services() to write them in an outputfile. Why does I need "$this->" the variable isn´t in the same function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using $this->

```
$command_in_hostfile = array();

class Host
{
    public $command_in_hostfile = array();

    function read_services()
    {   
        ...
        $this->command_in_hostfile[0] = array_merge($command_in_hostfile[0]);
        $this->command_in_hostfile[1] = array_merge($command_in_hostfile[1]);
        return($this->command_in_hostfile);
    }

    function write_hostfile()
    {
        foreach($this->command_in_hostfile as $key=>$value)
        {
        $checkcommand[$key] = "check_command ".$value."!".$value2_converted."\n";
        }   
    }
}
```